# Calculate time since event in a raster time series in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a time series of binomial data and I want to know the number of time steps since the last event (1). I am just not sure how to do this in R.

Here is an example data set. For each cell in the raster, I want to know the number of timesteps since a 1 was recorded.

```
r <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100)
r[] = rbinom(10000,1,.1)

for (i in 1:9){
  tmp = raster(nrow=100, ncol=100)
  tmp[] = rbinom(10000,1,.1)
  r = stack(r,tmp)
}

r = brick(r)
```

So for each cell of the raster brick, you would have a series (e.g. `c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)`). In this case the time to the event would by 4. I just can't figure out how to do this in a function that can be applied to the raster brick.

Comment: This is a rather cool question.

Comment: I am adapting this question/answer to identify a "time to event" for a threshold value in a time-series (eg., time to LAI > 4.9) and will put the function in the spatialEco package. It would still work for your problem, you would just set the threshold value to whatever value you are interested in so, for binomial `p=1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative using rle.

Write function to calculate run length to specified value. If the specified run value (y) is the first value it returns a 0 and if it is missing then a NA is returned.

```
time.to.event <- function(x, y=1, dir=c("LR", "RL")) {
    if(dir[1] == "RL") x <- rev(x)
      x.idx <- rle(x)$values
      e.idx <- rle(x)$lengths 
    if(x[1] == y) {
      e <- 0
    } else {
      e <- e.idx[which(x.idx == y)-1][1]
    }   
  return( e )
}
```

Test the function on your example, left-to-right (LR is default) and right-to-left (dir="RL").

```
time.to.event(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0))
time.to.event(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),dir="RL")
```

Now, apply it to a raster stack example

```
library(raster)
r <- do.call(raster::stack, replicate(20,raster::raster(matrix(sample(
             c(0,1), 1000, replace=TRUE), 100, 100))))
             
( t2e <- calc(r, fun=time.to.event) )
```

Comment: This works as well. Thanks. I hadn't ever seen `rle()`.

Comment: I selected this answer as the best because it was easier to reverse the order. Many times, time series data is older->more recent going left to write. I added `x = rev(x)` into the equation.

Comment: @user44796 I added a LR or RL option into the function to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `calc` with a function that finds the first one. The only complication is coping with not having any ones in the stack at any point, which I workaround here by testing and returning -1.

```
> fone= calc(r, fun=function(x){W=which(x==1); if(length(W)==0){return(-1)};return(min(W))})
```

To check, the first pixel out is:

```
> fone[1,1]
[1] 7
```

which comes from:

```
> r[1,1]
     layer.1.1.1 layer.2.1.1 layer.1.2.1 layer.2.2.1 layer.1.1.2 layer.2.1.2
[1,]           0           0           0           0           0           0
     layer.1.2.2 layer.2.2.2 layer.1 layer.2
[1,]           1           0       0       0
>
```

which has a 1 in the 7th position.

Couple more tests:

```
> fone[50,50]
[1] -1
```

So there shouldn't be any 1s in the raster at (50,50):

```
> r[50,50]
     layer.1.1.1 layer.2.1.1 layer.1.2.1 layer.2.2.1 layer.1.1.2 layer.2.1.2
[1,]           0           0           0           0           0           0
     layer.1.2.2 layer.2.2.2 layer.1 layer.2
[1,]           0           0       0       0
```

and (20,21) has more than 1:

```
> r[20,21]
     layer.1.1.1 layer.2.1.1 layer.1.2.1 layer.2.2.1 layer.1.1.2 layer.2.1.2
[1,]           1           0           0           0           0           0
     layer.1.2.2 layer.2.2.2 layer.1 layer.2
[1,]           0           0       1       0
```

and we catch the first one:

```
> fone[20,21]
[1] 1
```

There's probably a neater expression for the function that does it without an "if" but my brain is not up to it right now. Will edit if I think of it.

Thought.

Stick a "1" on the end of the vector of values being tested as a "guard value", then you know that `which` will definitely find something, and if it returns the number of layers in `r` plus 1, its found the guard value:

```
firstone = function(x){min(which(c(x,1)==1))}
fone = calc(r, firstone)
```

and if you want to set the pixels with no ones to something:

```
fone[fone == nlayers(r)+1] = NA
```

or whatever.

You say that

```
c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0))
```

should return 4, but my code will return 5. Subtract one from the value in my function.